# Add new property to existing object - c#

Tags: c#, object

When both 'if' condition is satisfied, I want `Start` to be added to the same `DataList` along with value and time.

```
public List<object> DataList = new List<object>();

if(somecondition)
{     
    DataList.Add(new { Value = Value, Time = time}); // assume this is DataList[0]
    //var start = null;
    //DataList.Add(new { Value = Value, Time = time, Start = start}); 
}

if(somecondition)  
{
    -> how do I add `start` to DataList[0] here.
    //DataList.Add(new { Start = start });
    //DataList[0]?.Start  = start;   
}
```

Later, when I use DataList, it should contain values from both `if` condition. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you simply declare a class with all the fields you need? Why do you use `List<object>`? Why do you add anonymous types to it? C# is not Python.

Comment: If you need add dynamic properties, you should use `Expando object`

Comment: In your example I recommand use Tuple instead of anonymous object

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will use a class instead.

Comment: @daremachine - How would a tuple help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options.

Use inheritance:

```
void Method()
{
    /* init variables */

    if (someCondition)
    {
        DataList.Add(new Data() { Value = Value, Time = time });
    }
    else if (someOtherCondition)
    {
        DataList.Add(new DataWithStart() { Value = Value, Time = time, Start = start });
    }
}

public List<Data> DataList = new List<Data>();

public class Data
{
    public string Value;
    public string Time;
}

public class DataWithStart : Data
{
    public string Start;
}
```

Or, use `ExpandoObject`:

```
void Method()
{
    /* init variables */

    dynamic data = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();

    if (someCondition)
    {
        data.Value = Value;
        data.Time = time;
    }
    
    if (someOtherCondition)
    {
        data.Start = start;
    }
    
    DataList.Add(data);
}

public List<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject> DataList = new List<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject>();
```

Comment: Using class is perfect. Thank you. But I wont be able to add "DataList.Add(new DataWithStart() { Value = Value, Time = time, Start = start });". As I wont have 'value' and 'time' data inside second if condition. I should  be able to add like DataList.Add(new DataWithStart() { Start = start }). May I know how can I achieve this.

Comment: If DataList[0] has 'time' and 'value' added during first 'if' condition, Should add 'start' property to same DataList[0] during second 'if' condition. So, DataList[0] will have all three properties when accessed later.

Comment: Re your first comment - use two separate classes and have `DataList` as a `List<object>`. For your second comment, then `ExpandoObject` is the way to go. However, it sounds like you have 4 situations to cover, with each condition being true or false. Is that right?

Comment: @st27 - Then use a nested if.

Comment: Answer was very helpful. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;

List<dynamic> DataList = new List<dynamic>();

dynamic data1 = new ExpandoObject();

if (someCondition)
{
    data1.Value = Value;
    data1.Time = time;
}

if (someCondition)
{
    data1.Start = start;
}

DataList.Add(data1);
```

you can use `ExpandoObject` to solve in simplest way.

Comment: Explain your code, please. And explain the pitfalls of using dynamic. How would one _use_ the DataList, given that its contents may or may not have a Start property?